# Length of inclined plane for the work required to raise 400lb block 3ft to be equal to 1/3 of the work required to just pick it up?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work

You are given a block that weighs 400 pounds that needs to raised vertically 3 feet. You could just pick it up, but we are given the task of designing an inclined plane that (when we push the block up it) will result in a work required that is equal to 1/3 of the work required to just pick it up vertically. Specifically, we are asked for the length of the inclined plane.

Known:

- Work = Force * Distance

My assumptions:

- There is no friction between the block and the inclined plane.
- The length of the inclined plane they are asking for is the hypotenuse of the triangle (inclined plane).
- The height of the triangle is the vertical height the block must be lifted, 3 ft.

Let:

x = length of the inclined plane, feet
w1 = work required to lift the block vertically
w2 = work required to move the block, x feet, up the inclined plane
F = force applied to the block, parallel to the inclined plane, which moves it the distance x
theta = angle of the inclined plane
a = length of the base of the inclined plane

My failed attempt:

w1 = 400 lb * 3 ft = 1200 ft-lb
w1 = 3 * w2
therefore,
w2 = w1/3 = 1200/3 = 400 ft-lb

w2 = F * x = 400
x = 400 / F

F = weight * sin(theta)
F = 400 * sin(theta)

therefore,
x = 400 / (400 * sin(theta))
x = 1 / sin(theta)  ...                        Equation[1]

We also know...
sin(theta) = 3 / x  ...                        Equation[2]

Buy solving Eq[1] and Eq[2] as a system of equations, we get
x = 1 / (3/x)
x = x / 3
1 = 1 / 3

Which would then show there is no solution, but I know there is a solution.

If I try another relationship for the 2nd equation in my system...
a^2 + 3^2 = x^2

with ( cos(theta) = a / x ), the above equation becomes

x^2 * cos(theta)^2 + 9 = x^2

with Eq[1], this becomes
(cos(theta)^2 / sin(theta)^2) + 9 = 1 / sin(theta)^2

BUT... the only solutions to this are integer multiples of 2pi.

So, the answer is 9, but I can't seem to prove why it's 9.
Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Levers, pulleys, and ramps can all modify forces and grant a [mechanical advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_advantage).  You can make the *force* required to lift the box smaller.  You cannot make the *work* required to lift the box smaller.

We can gain $mgh$ energy/work by lowering the box from the given height.  If we could raise it up there with less work, we would be able to repeat the process and retrieve arbitrary amounts of energy.

I suspect the problem intended to ask for the ramp that allows for one-third of the force required to lift the box directly, but that is speculation.

Comment: Correct, it does say effort! Thanks then I can just use the mechanical advantage formula. Mechanical advantage of an inclined plane = length of slope ÷ height of plane.  Thank you!!

Comment: @C-137 “Effort” is not a physics term and it shouldn’t be used in physics problems because it just causes confusion.